# Error in calling StartService while in setOnClickListener onCreate

Tags: android, onclick, togglebutton

I have an activity which calls a service through

```
startService(new android.content.Intent(this,NeglectedService.class);
```

I am trying to add a ToggleButton, that while isChecked(True) the service will run, and vice versa.

```
        toggleService = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.btnStopStartService);
    toggleService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if(toggleService.isChecked())
            {
                // Start the service
                showToast("true");
                startService(new Intent(this,NeglectedService.class));
            }
            else
            {
                // Pause/Stop the service
                showToast("false");
            }
        }
    });
```

But calling this way returns an error, I don't know how to tackle

```
The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<NeglectedService>) is undefined
```

If I remove the new Intent(this, NeglectedService.class) than the error dissappears, but the service is not called (ofc, the activity doesn't know who to call)

So, my question:
- How can I monitor and start/stop a service from my activity?

Question: How can I control a service state from the activity that created it? 
I have a togglebutton.onclicklistener. I want that when the toggle is ON, the service will run, and stop wehn toggled to off. 
I will use sharedpreferences to store the service state, but I get an error when calling startService(new android.content.Intent(this,NeglectedService.class); from the if(toggleService.isChecked())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor that you are trying to use takes a `Context` as its first argument, but `this` isn't an instance of `Context`, it's the anonymous on-click listener that you are declaring.  To pass the outer instance you need to qualify it:

```
startService(new Intent(MyActivity.this, NeglectedService.class));
```

where `MyActivity` is the name of your activity class.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the scope of `this` in your Intent instantiation. Where you are calling it,`this` refers to an instance of `View.OnClickListener`, but it needs to be an instance of `android.content.Context`.

I do not know the name if your Activity which contains the code snippet that you have included, but if is named `MyActivityClass`then you need to replace `this`with `MyActivityClass.this`.